# How do you "deflate" menus in android?

Tags: android, android-contextmenu

I have a contextual action bar, where I have a setting called "DELETE". When I press that button I want the CAB menu to disappear.

```
                class MyActionModeCallBack implements android.view.ActionMode.Callback {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onCreateActionMode(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                        actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.event_menu, menu);
                        return true;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public boolean onActionItemClicked(android.view.ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem menuItem) {
                        int id = menuItem.getItemId();

                        if (id == R.id.delete) {
                                          *******
                            _root.removeView(view);

                            // This is where I want to remove the CAB menu
                                          *******
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onDestroyActionMode(android.view.ActionMode actionMode) {
                        ((RelativeLayout)view).removeAllViews();
                        view.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
                        view.setTag(R.string.viewSelected, "0");
                    }
                }
```

I was thinking about calling the `onDestroyActionMode()` right after the `_root.removeView(view);`, but I don't know what arguments to pass in.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to hide the item being selected, you can call

```
menuItem.setVisible(false);
```

Alternatively, if you want to remove all items from the menu, you can call

```
optionsMenu.clear();
```

in the onActionItemClicked() method.
You can save your menu to a field in your onCreateOptionsMenu method as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    optionsMenu = menu
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `actionMode.finish()`.  This will invoke the `onDestroyActionMode()` callback.